# Access to XMLHttpRequest from origin has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:

Tags: java, reactjs, servlets, axios, cors

I am building a front end app using React and my backend is built using Java (Dynamic Web Application).

I am doing a **"PUT"** request to the backend to  perform update request on a data.
The backend URL request works fine on POSTMAN but while sending same request from React shows CORS policy error even if I have set Header (Access-Control-Allow-Origin)  to allow all requests.

How do I resolve this issue. GET request is working fine but POST, PUT and DELETE request is showing *blocked by CORS policy*.

This is my backend code :

```
// PUT: servlet for single ID
protected void doPut(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String doc_id = request.getParameter("doc_id");
    // request body
    String body = request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));

    // response status
    Integer status = null;
    try {
        status = mySQLconnector.updateDataById(doc_id, body);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // set headers
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");


    // write data
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    if (status == 1) {
        writer.write("doc_id : " + doc_id + " fields updated successfully in DB ...");
    } else {
        writer.write("failed to update the fields in DB !");
    }

    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}
```

This is my Front end code :

```js
const handleProceed = async () => {
        if (invoice_currency && cust_payment_terms) {
            const jsonBody = JSON.stringify(data);
            const doc_id = ids[0];
            const res = await axios({
                method: "PUT",
                url: `http://localhost:8080/InvoiceBackend/DataServlet?doc_id=${doc_id}`,
                data: jsonBody,
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
            });
            console.log(res);
        }
        setIds([]);
        handleClose();
    };
```

The exact error message looks like this :

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you make an HTTP request to an API, the first request that is sent by the browser is the preflight request (OPTIONS request). This method requests permitted communication options for a given URL. You can try setting the headers by handling the OPTIONS request. That is, you can handle the preflight request with the help of the doOptions() method.

```
    protected void doOptions(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
              throws ServletException, IOException {
          setAccessControlHeaders(response);
          response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK  );
    }
     
    private void setAccessControlHeaders(HttpServletResponse resp) {
          resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
          resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
          resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
          
     }
```